# MP3 Album Detection

Tags: mp3

I see how many applications like MusicMatch, detects (only introducing a music CD) wich albums it is. I think that it uses songs duration... but, anyone knows how it is done for sure??

Comment: This is a programming related Q&A site. In your question I can't see any programming related subject, so voting to move to http://superuser.com where you might get more appropriate answers.

Comment: Here is the programming issue:

Is there a php implementation of this??

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly a service such as [CDDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDDB) or [MusicBrainz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz) is used. CDDB uses track duration only, while MusicBrainz uses [acoustic fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) through the [MusicDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicDNS) service.

Comment: Is there a php implementation of this??